# Authenticate to K8s as specific user

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I recently built an EKS cluster w/ Terraform. In doing that, I Created 3 different roles on the cluster, all mapped to the same AWS IAM Role (the one used to create the cluster)

Now, when I try to manage the cluster, RBAC seems to use the least privileged of these (which I made a view role) that only has read-only access.

Is there anyway to tell config to use the admin role instead of view?

I'm afraid I've hosed this cluster and may need to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

**Some into**

You don't need to create a mapping in K8s for an IAM entity that created an EKS cluster, because by default it will be mapped to `"system:masters"` K8s group automatically. So, if you want to give additional permissions in a K8s cluster, just map other IAM roles/users.

In EKS, IAM entities are used authentication and K8s RBAC are for authorization purposes. The mapping between them is set in `aws-auth` configMap in `kube-system` namespace,

**Back to the question**

I'm not sure, why K8s may have mapped that IAM user to the least privileged K8s user - it may be the default behaviour (bug?) or due to the mapping record (for `view` perms) being later in the CM, so it just re-wrote the previous mapping.

Any way, there is no possibility to specify a K8s user to use with such mapping.

Also, if you used `eksctl` to spin up the cluster, you may try creating a new mapping as [per docs](https://eksctl.io/usage/iam-identity-mappings/), but not sure if that will work.

Some reading reference: [#1](https://itnext.io/kubernetes-part-4-aws-eks-authentification-aws-iam-authenticator-and-aws-iam-5985d5af9317), [#2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I mapped the IAM role to all the k8s roles on purpose to see what the behavior was. It looks like it forces the IAM role against the least privileged binding. Since I used the owner IAM Role, I was wondering if there was any way around it. I don't think there is, and ended up destroying the cluster with notes to make new roles for any further mappings and reserve owner role.